# Upload image from IPhone in asp.net

Tags: iphone, asp.net

I don't know anything about Objective C. I am developing a website in asp.net for
  mobile version. And in this application I need to upload an image from mobile.
  But uploading from iPhone not working. After searching I found this link

[Post image and text from iPhone to asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136288/post-image-and-text-from-iphone-to-asp-net)

Where a xcode is used.

The problem is that I don't know how to use this code in my application. I can understand
  handler used for uploading but not Objective C code. And can any one help me how to 
  use this code on IIS server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your application is a website (that is, if it's going to be accessed solely by the web browser on the device), then Objective C code isn't what you're looking for at all.  Your website won't be able to execute compiled native code on the device.  When you say that the upload from an iPhone isn't working, can you be more specific?  What is the observed behavior?  What does the application receive as a request?  Are there client-side debugging tools on the device that you use?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My application is website which can only accessed by web browser from iphone or other devices.On iphone the browse button of fileupload control is disabled.Is there any other way to upload file from Iphone.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue, with a _potential_ workaround (I haven't personally used it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784352/iphone-file-upload-with-html  I imagine the core of the issue is that iOS doesn't allow file system access to the user, so its browser simply doesn't support the file input element.

Answer (score 0):

I have quite an old blog about posting files to asp.net site from iOS. You can check it out at -

http://mahmudulislam.me/2011/09/14/uploading-files-from-iphone-to-asp-net-web-site/

This might help you.